# Switching between different Firefoxes

Tags: keyboard, spaces, mission-control, firefox

Similar and related to #54788 here, but different.

I use separate Firefox profiles for personal use and work, and I often have both open at the same time, in different Mission Control "spaces", both full screen but possibly sharing the space with other apps. My problem is how to reliably switch *with the keyboard* to one of the Firefoxes, and not the other. It seems several peculiarities of the Mac UI and of Firefox profiles implementation conspire to make this impossible.

I can't do it with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> because Mac always represents apps there just with the bare name, not with their window name. Thus all I see in the <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> widget are two Firefox icons both labelled "Firefox".

I can't do it with <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> because apparently, Mac considers the two Firefoxes two different apps, and this shortcut only switches windows of the same app.

A better try was Mission Control because it at least shows thumbnails of each window and my two Firefoxes are easily told apart this way. But now the problem is that MC shortcuts really only switch between *spaces* and not apps; after I switch to the right space, I still can end up in the *other* app in this space, and there still isn't any clear way to switch to the Firefox in the same space (and not the other Firefox).

Any ideas?

Comment: To reformulate this with maybe a narrower scope: is there a way to switch between Mission Control "side by side" apps, with the keyboard? If not why tf not? Isn't that something widely needed for accessibility?